# What are the effects of cat anti-flea insecticide - imidacloprid - on humans?

Tags: cats, safety, fleas, pest-control

I'm using Bayer's Advantage Anti-fleas drops for my cat. It is a very common in Europe and is effective. However,
I have also suffer from dry eyes and I've noticed that when I apply this product to my cat I get puffy eyes and generally feel rather lethargic for a day or so, as my cat does.

I read in the product's official [site](https://www.advantagepetcare.com.au/au/our-products/advantage/advantage-cats/#:%7E:text=Advantage%20contains%20an%20active%20ingredient,flea%20larvae%20in%20the%20home.) that:

> Advantage contains an active ingredient, **imidacloprid**, that works fast and is able to kill fleas on contact, as it is not absorbed
> into the bloodstream. The active ingredient remains in the lipid
> (oily/fatty) layer of your cat’s skin and fur. It also kills flea
> larvae in the home.

But if I've learned anything, is that the Big Pharma's reassuring cannot be trusted at all.

Also I read in [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2662424/#:%7E:text=Mild%20clinical%20effects%20such%20as,%2C%20%5B21%5D%20are%20reported.) article that:

> Data on human exposure to **imidacloprid** is limited to occupational
> exposures and 13 case reports of self-poisoning. Mild clinical effects
> such as tachycardia, hypertension, mydriasis, nausea and vomiting
> occur, but more serious sequelae including respiratory failure,
> seizures and even death are reported. This raises serious doubts about
> its assumed superior safety profile over older insecticides. However,
> in the majority of cases the concentration of imidacloprid was not
> quantified so it was not possible to confirm exposure or consider dose
> in the risk assessment.

So I'm wondering if there are any solid scientific facts about side effects of 'imidacloprid' on pet owners? And if imidacloprid is indeed dangerous, are there safer alternatives?